# React Native Chrome Custom Tabs is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to add `react-native-custom-tabs` in my project, but problem is that It's showing

> cannot read property `openURL` of undefined.

```js
import CustomTabs from 'react-native-custom-tabs';

class HomeScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: []
    };
    this.onPressListener = this.onPressListener.bind(this);
  }

  async onPressListener(event) {
    try {
      const url = 'https://www.google.com';
      CustomTabs.openURL(url);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message)
    }
  }
}
```

I installed it using yarn add react-native-custom-tabs
then I linked it with react-native link react-native-custom-tabs

Comment: which version of RN are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing like `import {CustomTabs} from 'react-native-custom-tabs';` instead of `import CustomTabs from 'react-native-custom-tabs';`

hope it helps. feel free for doubts